# hovering data as a text in inside container

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-express

query is that hovering data does not appear as a text in child container on showing dashboard, but when I click on the child container this hovering data should appear as a text on this container.

```
HOVER_DATA = ['Name','Country','Currency','Market Capitalization', 'Most Recent Quarter','PE Ratio%','PEG Ratio%','Earnings Share','Dividend Yield','Operating Margin TTM','Return OnAssets TTM','Return OnEquity TTM','Quarterly Earnings GrowthYOY','Quarterly Revenue GrowthYOY','dailyChange']
value_attribute = 'Market Capitalization'
Hover_Tmp = '<br>Name:%{customdata[0]}'+'<br>Country:%{customdata[1]}'+'<br>Currency:%{customdata[2]}'+'<br>Daily Change: %{customdata[14]}%'+'<br>Market Capitalization:%{value:0.3s}'+'<br>Most Recent Quarter:%{customdata[4]}' +'<br>PE Ratio:%{customdata[5]}%'+'<br>PEG Ratio:%{customdata[6]}%'+'<br>Earnings Share:%{customdata[7]}%' +  '<br>Dividend Yield:%{customdata[8]}' + '<br>Operating Margin TTM:%{customdata[9]}' + '<br>Return OnAssets TTM:%{customdata[10]}' + '<br>Return OnEquity TTM:%{customdata[11]}' + '<br>Quarterly Earnings GrowthYOY:%{customdata[12]}' + '<br>Quarterly Revenue GrowthYOY:%{customdata[13]}'+'<br>'

df['Symbol'] = df['Symbol'].apply(lambda item: link_ref.format(item, item, "{}")) 
df = pd.DataFrame(df) 

def create_dropdown(option, id_value):
    return html.Div(
        [dcc.Dropdown(id=id_value, options=option, value=option[0])]
    )

layout = html.Div([
        html.Div(
                children=[html.H1('Stock Market Summary',),
                html.P('''AI predictions, intraday market price action, biggest movers, H1 sectors performance, and more.''',
                )], id="header", className="row flex-display header", style={"display": "flex", "flex-direction": "column"},),
        html.Div([
                html.Div([
                    dcc.Graph(id="indicator")], className="graph create_container2 twelve columns"),
                    ], className="row flex-display"),

        html.Div([
            html.Div([
                html.H3('Thank You',)],className="footer create_container2 twelve columns",)
            ]),

    ],className="main",id="mainContainer",
                  style = {'backgroundColor':'#3d3d3b', 'textAlign': 'center',"display": "flex", "flex-direction": "column"
                }
)

@dash.callback(
    Output('indicator','figure'),
    Input(component_id='dd-output-container', component_property='value')
)
```

```
def update_output(theme_select, my_date_picker_single,dd_output_container):
    """
        Updating Tree MAp as per filter
    """
    if theme_select == 'Dark Theme': 
        color_discrete_map=["#ff4d00","#21b811"] 
    filtered_df = filter_df(my_date_picker_single,dd_output_container) 
    if filtered_df.empty: 
        print("Dataframe is empty") 
        return "DATAFRAME IS EMPTY" 
        # pymsgbox.alert('Data Not Available', 'Alert')
        # print('***********',None)
```

```
    else:
        print("NOT EMPTY") 
        indicator = px.treemap(filtered_df,
                    color=COLOR,
                    color_continuous_scale=color_discrete_map,
                    path = ['Sector','Symbol','dailyChange',], 
                    maxdepth=3,
                    hover_data=HOVER_DATA, 
                    values=value_attribute, 
                    custom_data=HOVER_DATA,
                    color_discrete_map=color_discrete_map)
```

```
        indicator.update_traces(textfont_size=22) 
        
        indicator.update_layout(margin = dict(t=35, l=5, r=5, b=5),
                        paper_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,255,0)', 
                        plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,255,0)', 
                        )
       
        indicator.data[0].texttemplate ="<b>%{label}</b><br>Market Cap.:%{value:0.3s}"
 return indicator
```

I am expecting that, my inner child container should have same complete text as in hover data.
I am uploading my screen shot step by step:-

[image: this is the screen shot of my dashboard]
[image: ihis hovering data does not appear as a text on this child container]
[image: right side hovering data should also appear as a text]

Comment: Isn't it just a typo when you call `@dash` in the `Output(`, `indicator` is with two 'r' (`indicatorr`).

Comment: I just edited the code and its still not working as expected